# React Native - start Animated twice, an error start of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-animatable

```
animation = new Animated.Value(0);

animationSequnce = Animated.sequence(
    [Animated.timing(this.animation, { toValue: 1 }),
      Animated.timing(this.animation, { toValue: 0, delay: 1000 }),
    ],
  );

startAnimation = () => {
  animationSequnce.start();
}

stopAnimation = () => {
  animationSequnce.stop();
}
```

I want to start an `animation sequence` several times.

I tested it by writing code that calls `startAnimation` when the button is pressed.
The animation runs on the first run.
When the second button is clicked after the first animation is finished
`Cannot read property 'start' of undefined` error occurs.

```
startAnimation = () => {
  Animated.sequence(
    [Animated.timing(this.animation, { toValue: 1 }),
      Animated.timing(this.animation, { toValue: 0, delay: 1000 }),
    ],
  ).start();
}
```

This change to `startAnimation` will not cause an error, but you will not be able to call `stopAnimation` because it will call a different `AnimationSequnce` each time.

What is the best way to use an animation multiple times?

Comment: Why don`t you put this animation to your state?

Comment: @AbdumutalAbdusamatov 
Is there a difference between putting an animation in a state and not putting it in a state?
When I test it both do the same.
So I didn't put it.

Answer (score 0):

to stop animation

```
this.animation.stopAnimation()
```

optional get callBack when the animation stop

```
this.animation.stopAnimation(this.callback())
```

or

```
Animated.timing(
  this.animation
).stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `Animated.sequence()`, react native creates a variable `current`, refers to the index of the current executing animation, and stores it locally.

When `Animated.sequence().start()` finished, the variable `current` won't be cleaned or reset to 0, so the second time you call `start()` on the same sequenced animation, the array index out of bound and cause error.

It's a hidden bug of react native, below is the implementation of `Animated.sequence`

```
const sequence = function(
  animations: Array<CompositeAnimation>,
): CompositeAnimation {
  let current = 0;
  return {
    start: function(callback?: ?EndCallback) {
      const onComplete = function(result) {
        if (!result.finished) {
          callback && callback(result);
          return;
        }

        current++;

        if (current === animations.length) {
          callback && callback(result);
          return;
        }

        animations[current].start(onComplete);
      };

      if (animations.length === 0) {
        callback && callback({finished: true});
      } else {
        animations[current].start(onComplete);
      }
    },

    stop: function() {
      if (current < animations.length) {
        animations[current].stop();
      }
    },

    reset: function() {
      animations.forEach((animation, idx) => {
        if (idx <= current) {
          animation.reset();
        }
      });
      current = 0;
    },

    _startNativeLoop: function() {
      throw new Error(
        'Loops run using the native driver cannot contain Animated.sequence animations',
      );
    },

    _isUsingNativeDriver: function(): boolean {
      return false;
    },
  };
};
```

My solution is to define a custom sequence, and manually reset `current` to 0 when the sequenced animations finished:

```
const sequence = function(
  animations: Array<CompositeAnimation>,
): CompositeAnimation {
  let current = 0;
  return {
    start: function(callback?: ?EndCallback) {
      const onComplete = function(result) {
        if (!result.finished) {
          current = 0;
          callback && callback(result);
          return;
        }

        current++;

        if (current === animations.length) {
          current = 0;
          callback && callback(result);
          return;
        }

        animations[current].start(onComplete);
      };

      if (animations.length === 0) {
        current = 0;
        callback && callback({finished: true});
      } else {
        animations[current].start(onComplete);
      }
    },

    stop: function() {
      if (current < animations.length) {
        animations[current].stop();
      }
    },

    reset: function() {
      animations.forEach((animation, idx) => {
        if (idx <= current) {
          animation.reset();
        }
      });
      current = 0;
    },

    _startNativeLoop: function() {
      throw new Error(
        'Loops run using the native driver cannot contain Animated.sequence animations',
      );
    },

    _isUsingNativeDriver: function(): boolean {
      return false;
    },
  };
};
```